# Localhost connecting but database not connecting with Wamp

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, database-connection

While using wamp server on localhost everything was working as supposed to. Then I happened to click on wamp icon and might have clicked on some configuration setting. Happened a bit quickly so don't remember what exactly happened( just a random button click) But I think I was on this menu when the button was clicked.

[image: The menu on which the button was clicked]

After that the Wamp server restarted and since then I can't connect to the database using my CodeIgniter projects.
When I try to open a project it throws this error
[image: The error it throws when I open a project]

When I tried to debug my code to verify the problem in one of my CodeIgniter project's files( in the config/database.php file).
I put this code to know what is the problem.

```
    echo '<pre>';
  print_r($db['default']);
  echo '</pre>';

  echo 'Connecting to database: ' .$db['default']['database'];
  $dbh=mysql_connect
  (
    $db['default']['hostname'],
    $db['default']['username'],
    $db['default']['password'])
    or die('Cannot connect to the database because: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ($db['default']['database']);

    echo '<br />   Connected OK:'  ;
    die( 'file: ' .__FILE__ . ' Line: ' .__LINE__);
```

After that, it shows why the database cannot be connected. Here is what it shows now.

[image: The Real problem]

What is a possible solution?

Comment: Try setting hostname to 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to connect to your DB via phpMyAdmin? Does it work?

It's hard to tell what you did there, but to save time I suggest you just:

Connect via phpMyAdmin export you DataBase, reinstall your WAMP and put back your DB.

Comment: Yes, I can see all my databases via phpMyAdmin. On starting the Wamp shows green to indicate everything is working fine.

Comment: I think backing up all the databases and source code and reinstalling the wamp might be the best bet

Answer (score 0):

Check the below steps, it will be helpful:

When you use just "localhost" the MySQL client library tries to use a Unix domain socket for the connection instead of a TCP/IP connection. The error is telling you that the socket, called MySQL, cannot be used to make the connection, probably because it does not exist (error number 2).

From the MySQL Documentation:

On Unix, MySQL programs treat the host name localhost specially, in a way that is likely different from what you expect compared to other network-based programs. For connections to localhost, MySQL programs attempt to connect to the local server by using a Unix socket file. This occurs even if a --port or -P option is given to specify a port number. To ensure that the client makes a TCP/IP connection to the local server, use --host or -h to specify a host name value of 127.0.0.1, or the IP address or name of the local server. You can also specify the connection protocol explicitly, even for localhost, by using the --protocol=TCP option.

There are a few ways to solve this problem.

You can just use TCP/IP instead of the Unix socket.

You would do this by using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost when you connect.

The Unix socket might by faster and safer to use, though. You can change the socket in php.ini: open the MySQL configuration file my.cnf to find where MySQL creates the socket, and set PHP's mysqli.default_socket to that path. On my system it's /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock.

Configure the socket directly in the PHP script when opening the connection. For example:

$db = new MySQLi('localhost', 'kamil', '***', '', 0, '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')